# My local git is said to be behind the remote master - is this a bug or?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code, bitbucket-server

I am the only user of this remote git repository. And I work only on one machine.

I avoid git command line and do "Commit all" and "Push" in vscode.
No other interaction with git.

And still I now get this. I suspect something went wrong because of network trouble.
But since my git fu is extremely weak I am very hesitating to test the suggested action here.
(I mean the data must be wrong somewhere.)

Ah, and this is on Windows 10. Maybe some special problem there?

And. vscode is in my opinion very buggy (but comfortable for me right now). Big problems with race conditions in the editor for me. (Using a cheap laptop.) So if I do a pull I will have to check everything very carefully.

What can I safely do?

```
> git push origin master:master
To bitbucket.org:HIDDEN.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'bitbucket.org:HIDDEN.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: You can do `git log master` and `git log origin/master` (maybe do `git fetch` first) to see what commits are at the respective branches.

Comment: `git log --all --decorate --graph --oneline` is a good way to visualize the branches together.

Comment: @chepner That was a useful one. I can see now where it went wrong. Same commit time etc, but different id:s. Though I have no idea yet how to proceed.

Comment: Hm, looks like I want to use "git revert" on the server? Is that correct? How do I do it? And can I just do a new "push" from my laptop after that?

Answer (score 2):

update your local branch with master branch

use

```
git rebase origin/master
```

If any merge conflict occurs resolve it. if not then you are lucky :).

Answer (score 2):

> What can I safely do?

Gather more information.

To find out what's going on, say `git fetch`. Now `git log origin/master` and also `git log master`, and you will see what commit `origin/master` has (reflecting the remote) that your local `master` does not.

From there, you can decide what to do.